# Regex for matchng anything between parenthesis

Tags: sed, grep, regular-expression

I have the following regex so far:

```
printf "this is (test.com)\n" | grep -Po '(?<=\().*(?=\))'
```

The above regex will print the desired output, which is **test.com**

As far as I am adding new parenthesis to my code

```
printf "this is (test.com) and (alex)\n" | grep -Po '(?<=\().*(?=\))'
```

, it displays something like:

**test.com) and (alex**

I would like my regex to print anything between brackets (no matter how many there are). More, I would like to add a condition to print just words between brackets with a specific length.

Eg: (aaa) test1 (bbb) test test (ccc) test (example) (ddd)

I just want printed out the words between brackets that have length 3. So the output should be:

***aaa bbb ccc ddd***

Comment: Use `[^)]` instead `.` or if you already use -P (pcre regex) to prohibit regex be greedy you should add `?` after `*`: `grep -Po '(?<=\().*?(?=\))'`

Comment: That worked. What about the lenght condition ? Where should I place it, and how ... in order to print words with only 3 characters ?

Comment: You have to study `quantificator` thoroughly. Three characters can be choised like `...` (any 3 symbols) or, for example `\w{3}` (any 3 alphanumeric symbols)

Answer (score 1):

Please be noted that expression try to choice the pattern of **maximum** length (`gready regex`) match. As you see in your example (regex: symbols between parenthesis) have choiced

- ...*is ( **test.com) and (alex** )*

instead of

- ...*is (**test.com**) and (**alex**)*.

There are two ways to override such behavior:

1. Substitute `any symbol` by `revers match` of limit or devide symbol (for example: `(.*)` by `([^)]*)`
2. Modern regular expressions (PCRE for example) allow a quantifier to be specified as *lazy*. They put a question mark after the quantifier to make it lazy `.*?`. By using a lazy quantifier, the expression tries the minimal match first.

More over the first variant allows to some simplify regex: `grep -Po '\(\K[^)]*'`

Comment: Thank you for your response. I would vote this up but I don't have the necessary rep. Supposing that between paranthesis are just letters, it would be easier to add a length condition ?

Comment: Try to indicate the exact term for expression: *Output words in parenthesis which consist in 3 letter only*. Is it correct? `'\(\K\w\w\w(?=\))'` or `'\(\K\w{3}(?=\))'`

Comment: It worked. Thank you for your time. I will look into these so that I will have a better understanding into regex conditions